# Version control for binary files that doesn't store the files

Tags: git, version-control, binary, git-annex

OK, I have a large folder with millions of binary files. It is possible that these files are altered by a remote process, and I need to know when that happens, BUT… I don't want to store a second copy of these files (inside a repo) and I cannot modify or alter these files (e.g. moving them, and leaving a symlink in their place, a la git annex).

So, ideally this tool would track the files via their metadata, i.e. their size, modification date, and a file hash. Then, when running whatever equivalent of `git status`, I could see which files have been modified (i.e. their metadata no longer matches). I can then stage and commit those changes, thus, updating the metadata in the repo.

Obviously, I would not be able to restore or rollback anything from this repo.

Is this possible?

Git-Annex seemed pretty close, but I can't have the originals moved and replace with symlinks. I stumbled upon git-annex ["Direct Mode"](http://git-annex.branchable.com/direct_mode/), which SEEMINGLY does what I want, but I'm concerned that it's deprecated? Is that the best tool for this?

Comment: This sounds much more like a task for a database instead of git. You would store the metadata (date of creation/modification, file hash´and location) and then query the database whenever you need to access the file. This might help: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/learn-sql-simple-database-sqlite/

Comment: seems more like a question for SU.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a perfect job for the [tripwire](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tripwire/). Tripwire takes a snapshot of your files with the metadata you mentioned and lets you know, if those files are altered.